# How to make one box Collider 2D go through another in Unity?

Tags: unity, collision-avoidance

How can I make one Box Collider 2D go through another one in Unity? I tried [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.IgnoreCollision.html), but it seems to work only for ordinary Box Collider, but not for Box Collider 2D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Pyhsics2D.IgnoreCollision()` since Box Collider 2D inherits from **Collider2D**, not Collider. Found more info here, check [this one](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.IgnoreCollision.html) out.

Comment: It does not help. I need dynamic collision enabling/disabling from script.

Comment: I have changed the answer completely, since you have asked for dynamic collision handling. May be this one will help